# Xamarin forms picker binding did not display

Tags: firebase, xamarin, mvvm, binding, picker

I want to get the data from the firebase and binding into the picker but it did not display anything.

xaml

```
    <Picker Title="Select Category" ItemsSource="{Binding IncomeList}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
```

Viewmodel

```
public class AddIncomeViewModel{
     public List<Category> IncomeList { get; set; }
     private FirebaseHelper services;

   public AddIncomeViewModel{
     service = new FirebaseHelper();
     IncomeList = new List<Category>();
     GetIncomeList();
   }

public async void GetIncomeList()
        {
            
            try
            {
                
                List<Category> income = await services.GetIncome();
                foreach (Category incomes in income)
                {
                    IncomeList.Add(new Category
                    {
                        Name = incomes.Name,
                        CategoryType = incomes.CategoryType
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            
        }

}
```

It did not have any error but display nothing.If I add this line of code it will work fine.

```
IncomeList.Add(new Category
                {
                    Name = "Salary",
                    CategoryType = "Income"
                });
```

Can I know why this happen?

Comment: Please use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`

Comment: are you sure `GetIncomeList` is working?  It's an async method and you're not awaiting it.

Comment: Thank you Shaw. After I change to ObservableCollection, it work fine.

Comment: Ya, it is work.

Comment: After about 10 hours or trial and error, I found this question and the @Shaw answer.  It really was that simple.  I am using .Net MAUI with MVVM and in my view model,  ObservableCollection worked with Picker and List didn't.  Thank you!