# Picker in Xamarin Forms ItemDisplayBinding not binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a page in Xamarin, and I'm having issue binding to ItemDisplayBinding in the Picker. The code that I have is showing the main components of what I am trying to do to bind it. I am able to set ItemsSource="{Binding terms}" but if I try to set ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}", Visual Studio says "Member not found in data context 'SearchViewModel' and the Picker is not being populated. All of the solutions I looked at haven't helped me to solve this.

My Term model (in the models folder):

```
namespace ClassSearch.Models
{
    public class Term
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Term(string code, string name)
        {
            Code = code;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewPage:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ClassSearch.Views.SearchPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ClassSearch.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:SearchViewModel"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodel:SearchViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ...
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               ...
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
            <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameStyle}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
            <Picker Title="Select" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Terms}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                    />
        </Frame>
 </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My view Model:

```
public class SearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }
    public SearchViewModel()
    {
    Terms = new ObservableRangeCollection<Term>();
    }
    public async Task GetCurrentTerms()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        Terms = Terms ?? await CurrentTerm.GetTerms();
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

SearchPage.xaml.cs has the OnAppearing() overridden with

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (BindingContext is SearchViewModel vm)
        {
            await vm.GetCurrentTerms();
        }
     }
```

It appears this is the code causing the problem, but I don't see what the issue is.

```
public static class CurrentTerm
    {
        public static async Task<ObservableRangeCollection<Term>> GetTerms()
        {
            ObservableRangeCollection<Term> terms = new ObservableRangeCollection<Term>();
            //  YYYY/MM/DD
            DateTime currentDay = DateTime.Now.Date;
            DateTime SummerCheck = new DateTime(currentDay.Year, 11, 01);
            DateTime SpringCheck = new DateTime(currentDay.Year, 10, 01);
            DateTime FallCheck = new DateTime(currentDay.Year, 03, 01);
            if ((currentDay - SummerCheck).Days > 0)
            {
                var s = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100 + 1}4";
                var sp = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100 + 1}1";
                terms.Add(new Term(s, $"Summer {currentDay.Year + 1}"));
                terms.Add(new Term(sp, $"Spring {currentDay.Year + 1}"));
            }
            else if ((currentDay - SpringCheck).Days > 0)
            {
                var sp = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100 + 1}1";
                var f = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100}7";
                terms.Add(new Term(sp, $"Spring {currentDay.Year + 1}"));
                terms.Add(new Term(f, $"Fall {currentDay.Year}"));
            }
            else if ((currentDay - FallCheck).Days > 0)
            {
                var f = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100}7";
                var s = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100}4";
                terms.Add(new Term(f, $"Fall {currentDay.Year}"));
                terms.Add(new Term(s, $"Summer {currentDay.Year}"));
            }
            return terms;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you get your picker working?  I've been having the same problem and used the view model logic from this thread and it worked for me, although the SelectedItem still doesn't work.  But at least the picker is populating now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68664574/xamarin-forms-picker-binding-did-not-display

Comment: Yes my picker is working now. I'm not sure if you are doing this but for SelectedItem if your item source is `public List<Category>` for example, you need to bind SelectedItem to a property of type `Category`. So in the view model I would have `public Category Selected { get; set; }`, and bind SelectedItem to Selected.

Comment: Yes, I already had the SelectedItem of the same type as the ItemSource.  My issue turned out to be that I needed a setter that raised the OnPropertyChanged() event.  Like this:  private Category _selected; public Category Selected { get { return _selected; } set { _selected = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Selected)); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to i do not have the `CurrentTerm.GetTerms()`, i make a sample with adding data directly in `GetCurrentTerms` method for your reference.

Xaml:

```
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodel:SearchViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Picker Title="Select" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Terms}"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"                    
                /> <!--IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"-->
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }
    public SearchViewModel()
    {
        Terms = new ObservableRangeCollection<Term>();
    }
    public async Task GetCurrentTerms()
    {
        //IsBusy = true;
        //Terms = Terms ?? await CurrentTerm.GetTerms();
        //IsBusy = false;

        Term term1 = new Term("1", "a");
        Term term2 = new Term("2", "b");
        Term term3 = new Term("3", "c");
        Terms.Add(term1);
        Terms.Add(term2);
        Terms.Add(term3);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Remove the code in `OnAppearing`. Set the data in ViewModel like below.

```
public static class CurrentTerm
{
    public static ObservableRangeCollection<Term> terms { get; set; }
    static CurrentTerm()
    {
        terms = new ObservableRangeCollection<Term>();
        //  YYYY/MM/DD
        DateTime currentDay = DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime SummerCheck = new DateTime(currentDay.Year, 11, 01);
        DateTime SpringCheck = new DateTime(currentDay.Year, 10, 01);
        DateTime FallCheck = new DateTime(currentDay.Year, 03, 01);
        if ((currentDay - SummerCheck).Days > 0)
        {
            var s = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100 + 1}4";
            var sp = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100 + 1}1";
            terms.Add(new Term(s, $"Summer {currentDay.Year + 1}"));
            terms.Add(new Term(sp, $"Spring {currentDay.Year + 1}"));
        }
        else if ((currentDay - SpringCheck).Days > 0)
        {
            var sp = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100 + 1}1";
            var f = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100}7";
            terms.Add(new Term(sp, $"Spring {currentDay.Year + 1}"));
            terms.Add(new Term(f, $"Fall {currentDay.Year}"));
        }
        else if ((currentDay - FallCheck).Days > 0)
        {
            var f = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100}7";
            var s = $"2{currentDay.Year % 100}4";
            terms.Add(new Term(f, $"Fall {currentDay.Year}"));
            terms.Add(new Term(s, $"Summer {currentDay.Year}"));
        }
       
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class SearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public ObservableRangeCollection<Term> Terms { get { return CurrentTerm.terms; } }
    public SearchViewModel()
    {

    }
    //public async Task GetCurrentTerms()
    //{
    //    //IsBusy = true;
    //    //Terms = Terms ?? await CurrentTerm.GetTerms();        
    //    //IsBusy = false;

    //    //Term term1 = new Term("1", "a");
    //    //Term term2 = new Term("2", "b");
    //    //Term term3 = new Term("3", "c");
    //    //Terms.Add(term1);
    //    //Terms.Add(term2);
    //    //Terms.Add(term3);
    //}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your response. When I use your code for GetCurrentTerms, I am able to see the a,b,c. but when I switch it back to my code, I cannot. I added my GetTerms() function for your reference.

Comment: I would check it and feedback ASAP.

Comment: I replaced all of the logic in that function with Term term1 = new Term("1", "a"); terms.Add(term1); and it is still not working. I think I might be calling it incorrectly then, but I'm still not sure, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check my update.